# Not able to upload files into Azure blob from Application

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have an issue where we are able to upload files into Azure blob storage from local code but not from the application as is hosted on IIS inside EC2 instance .. Any idea as to what can be the possible reasons .

Comment: Could you please refer this [MSDN](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d30a6aa-16be-4c07-9dea-18d9f34c68f5/unable-to-connect-to-azure-blob-storage-from-iis?forum=windowsazuredata) once

Comment: Are you getting any error ?please provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible reasons for the **issue in uploading files into Azure blob from application.**

You can try with below points that might fix your issues:

1. In azure portal check the configuration of the storage whether it is correct version for storage client. Nowadays the **latest TLS version is 1.2 .**

If it is required lower version you can change by below:

**Go to Azure portal->storage->Configuration->Minimum TLS version.**

[image]

2. check with server which **IIS is installed once**. It might be some issues accessing the internet from that server.
3. Also check with **Firewall** in your system that allows the connection (protocol, host & port).
4. If TLS 1.2 is **enabled** check server with registry keys. if there is need to be added try to add the changes in registry keys.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols.

**Reference:** You can refer the blow links for troubleshooting.

1. [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470217/cannot-upload-to-azure-blob-storage-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400)
2. [Error-while-uploading-the-files-to-azure](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/b180a405-7bf3-4478-a42c-071cbe355708/error-while-uploading-the-files-to-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)